# Build a blog using node js, mysql and jade

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

I'm currently trying to build a blog using node.js, mysql and jade.
My question is that how I can save html or jade format text in the database and retrieve it properly. I want to use  in the middle of the text but it does not work.

these are the codes that I made,

app.js

```
app.get('/postnew', function(req,res){
    res.render('postnew.jade',{nickname:req.session.nickname});
});

app.post('/postnew', function(req,res){
  var nickname = req.session.nickname;
  var category = req.body.v_category;
  var title = req.body.v_title;
  var contents = req.body.contents;
  var time = moment().tz("Asia/Seoul").format("YYYY-MM-DD");
  var sql = 'INSERT INTO posts (nickname, category, title, content, time) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)'
  conn.query(sql, [nickname, category, title, contents, time], function(err, rows, fields){
    if(err){
      console.log(err);
      res.status(500).send('Internal Server Error');
    }else{
      res.redirect('/');
    }
  })
})
```

MySQL

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `posts` (
`id` int(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
`nickname` varchar(25) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
`category` text COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
`title` text COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
`content` text COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
`likes` int(20) NOT NULL,
`dislikes` int(20) NOT NULL,
`time` text COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
`reg_time` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
```

postnew.jade

```
 form(action="/postnew" class="sky-form" method='post')
          header New post
            fieldset
              section
                label.select
                  select(name="v_category")
                    option(value="0" selected disabled)
                      | Category
                    option(value="1")
                      | a
                    option(value="2")
                      | b
                    option(value="3")
                      | c
              section
                label.input
                  input(type="text" name="v_title" placeholder="title")
              section
                label(for="file" class="input input-file")
                  div.button
                    input(type="file" id="file" onchange="this.parentNode.nextSibling.value = this.value")
                    | Browse
                  input(type="text" readonly)
            fieldset
              section
                  label.textarea
                    //textarea(cols="80" id="v_contents" name="v_contents" rows="10")
                    textarea(cols="80" id="contents" name="contents" rows="10")
          footer.text-center
            button(type="submit" class="btn-u") Submit
            button(type="button" class="btn-u btn-u-default" onclick="window.history.back();") Back
```

index.jade

```
each post in posts
          h2
              | #{post.title}
          div.blog-post-tags
            ul.list-unstyled.list-inline.blog-info
              li
                i.fa.fa-calendar
                | &nbsp;#{post.time}
              li
                i.fa.fa-pencil
                | &nbsp;#{post.nickname}
              li
                i.fa.fa-comments
                | &nbsp;
              li
                i.fa.fa-folder-open-o
                if post.category == '1'
                  |&nbsp;a
                else if post.category == '2'
                  |&nbsp;b
                else if post.category == '3'
                  |&nbsp;c

          | #{post.content}
```

When you see the index.jade file, I am trying to retrieve the content in the `content` column. When I write a post like hahah and save it in the database, it shows all the tags due to | in front of #{post.content} and it retrieves the data improperly when I erase | .
If i better use other database, and view engine I'm willing to do so. So let me know.

Thank you for helping me in advance.
If my question is ambiguous, let me know.
Thank you.

Comment: Try `!{post.content}` also se this http://jade-lang.com/reference/interpolation/

Comment: Thank you for the comment. I have tried it and I weirdly solved my problem.